# What's the probability density of r.v. $Y = X + f(X)$ if the density of r.v. X is p(X)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is there a way to derive an expression for the density of the transformation of a continuous random variable $X$ (with prob. density $p(X)$ supported on $\mathbb{R}^d$) as follows?

$$Y = X + f(X)$$

What properties must $f$ satisfy for this to be possible?

I know that we can derive an expression for the density of a transformation $Z = f(X)$ when $f$ is a smooth, invertible function.

Comment: $Y=g (x)$ where $g(x)=x+f(x)$. So apply what you already know with $f$ changed to $g$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. However, is there a looser condition than the invertibility of $f$ in this case ($g(x) = x + f(x)$)?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\mathbb P(Y\le t) = \mathbb P(X + f(X)\le t)
$$
so if we have a formula for $f$, gathering the conditions for which $X + f(X)\le t$, we can retrieve the density probability function  $P_{X+f(X)}$ by differentiating $F_Y(t) = \mathbb P(Y\le t)$.

Example: $f=\rm Id$ gives $F_Y(t) = F_X(\frac t 2 )$.